# knockout template isn't able to handle DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout template feature to insert HTML templates in my page. The problem is, if I modify the DOM inserted by the template (for ex adding a span elem), the previously configured events (such as clicks) isn't triggered for the newly added elements.

Consider this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gp3Ef/

My template is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <p>From template</p>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="c" > click me! </span>
    </div>
</script>
```

And then I set an event to handle clicks on the span element. This works fine. 
Later after 2s, a new span is added:

```
<span class="c" > click me! (2)</span>
```

Since I'm using jquery's "on" the new span should also trigger the click event. This isn't happening, I'm having to re-define the click event (which is being done after 6s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery `on` you should add the event to an existing node and use a proper selector, the only change you need is to change this:

```
$('.c').on('click', function(){alert('clicked on span'); });
```

to

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.c', function(){alert('clicked on span'); });
```

this is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehranhatami/gp3Ef/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using KnockoutJS in a wrong way. KnockoutJS can handle events. Please check the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gp3Ef/5/

modified your template `<span data-bind="click:onclick" class="c" > click me! </span>`

and your viewmodel

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.name = ko.observable("hello");
    this.onclick=function(){
        alert('clicked on me');
    }
}
```

Have modified the fiddle with the complete features